# Force a line break after white space between words Jinja when inside if block

Tags: html, jinja2, ckan

I am using a framework called CKAN which uses Jinja2 as it's templating language.
I am trying to force a line break after every white space in the field.

[image]

So it will look like this

Names: test-test-2 
                   test-test-3 
                   test-test-4

This is my script:

```html
  {% for key, value in h.format_resource_items(res.items()) %} 
              {% if "Resource Names" == key.title() %}
                  <tr class="tr class"><th scope="row">{{ key.title() }}</th><td>{{ value }}</td></tr>
              {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried adding this

```
value|replace(' ', ', ')
```

and it does work meaning it replaces the white space with a comma and space after but if I try

```
value|replace(' ', '\n')
```

it doesn't do anything.

I also tried this

```
value|replace(' ', <br>)
```

but it breaks the website and if I put that inside quotation marks it replaces the white space with the actual values `<br>`

I have also tried, adding an id to the html and then adding CSS but nothing changes either.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, I needed to add **| safe** after the replace filter. The safe filter marks the string as safe, allowing it not be automatically escaped if auto escaping is enabled.

```
{{ value | replace(' ', '<br>') | safe }}
```